# How to get possible paths to permutate list A to B python3

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting, transform, swap

So I have two lists:

```
A = [5, 4, 2, 1, 3, 8, 7, 6, 9]
B = [2, 3, 4, 1, 9, 7, 8, 6, 5]
```

And i want to transform list A to be equal to B, example path:

```
IN [5, 4, 2, 1, 3, 8, 7, 6, 9] swap 4,2
   [5, 2, 4, 1, 3, 8, 7, 6, 9] swap 5,2
   [2, 5, 4, 1, 3, 8, 7, 6, 9] swap 8,7
   [2, 5, 4, 1, 3, 7, 8, 6, 9] swap 3,5
   [2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 7, 8, 6, 9] swap 5,9
   [2, 3, 4, 1, 9, 7, 8, 6, 5] == B
```

And i want to find all possible paths to do it or only the shortest

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem. What exactly are you stuck trying to implement a solution? Specifically, do you have any Python code yet if you are asking a Python question or are you looking for a general algorithm that can be written in any programming language? Be sure to read [help] on asking good questions

Comment: Related - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance

Comment: So textdistance.levenshtein.distance(A, B)  shows us how many objects in A have to be changed